# How can I add security to a mySQL column addition generated by user input?

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo, code-injection

Using PHP 7 and MySQL 8

Having a new column generated by the end user isn't the best idea in the first place, but in this situation (and others where common PDO tactics aren't easily used), what is the solution to provide security against SQL injection?

What I'm trying to do :
I have a dynamic registration form which takes it's inputs from the database, and the owners of this website can add fields to this form. Of course if a new field is added to the form, there must also be a new column added to the database to store the data. There is no problem doing this with a direct insert, but if someone hacked into the admin system they could easily add sql injection. Thus I'm trying to find a more secure method.

The Working (insecure) Code:

```
  //$fName is the field name and also the column name
  $fName= $_POST['fName'];
  $sql2=$pdo->prepare("ALTER TABLE attendee ADD $fName VARCHAR( 255 )");
  $go2=$sql2->execute();
```

What I've tried:
I've looked into whitelisting but I don't believe this is the best option as the possibilities for what the column may be named are endless.

```
//Tried using named paramater PDO array (also tried unnamed ? version)
  $data2=[
    'fName'=>$fName
         ];
  $sql2=$pdo->prepare("ALTER TABLE attendee ADD :fName VARCHAR( 255 )");
  $go2=$sql2->execute($data2);

//Using PDO Quote indirectly
  $roger=$pdo->quote($fName);
  $sql2=$pdo->prepare("ALTER TABLE attendee ADD $roger VARCHAR( 255 )");
  $go2=$sql2->execute();

//Using PDO Quote Directly with concatenation
  $sql2=$pdo->prepare("ALTER TABLE attendee ADD" . $pdo->quote($fName) . " VARCHAR( 255 )");
  $go2=$sql2->execute();
```

Comment: You could consider a whitelist of acceptable column names and checking that the name is in that list.

Comment: Ah thanks for the answer Nick! I'll also add that to what I've tried/considered. I don't think a whitelist would work in this situation, as what they'll name the column in the future is beyond me .

Comment: I'd just validate or filter the user choosen column name using regex. Only allow normal characters and format like e.g. /^[a-z][a-z0-9-]{1,20}$/i . After that it's safe to use. Don't forget to check for duplicate column names. Also important: use the backtick ` around column and table names.
But I second @Your Common Sense that numbered column names would work and is full PDO compatible. Adding columns in bulk (per 10 or so) will also minimize the table rebuilds.

Answer (score 0):

There is **absolutely no point** in naming extra columns based on user input.

Just name them extra_column1, extra_column2 etc.

For a totally automated system like yours it would be ok. For this system you would inevitably have to maintain sort of a map where a column name is linked to some metadata,  like display name etc, so just add extra_column1 to this map as a column name.

Comment: I've realized this solution, but this is a last resort as there is also a CSV generator which the company will use to get the information from the registration form. They have already been clear on wanting the header (column names) as part of the CSV, so having extra_column 1, extra_column_2, etc. will be unsatisfactory.

Comment: I don't get how it's a problem at all. You must use a display name, not a column name for a csv header. The same thing you show in the HTML table header and HTML form label.

Answer (score 0):

there is no difference either you add field or add column by SQL query because both write into database, so sql-injection is possible in both condition not only when adding column, specially if you directly passing user-input into SQL query without escaping unwanted character.

So Just care of user input, properly sanitize all input.

thanks,
jaikey sarraf